# Indetermination in a complex fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, complex

I determined the complex Fourier series of a sinusoidal signal and arrived at the following expression:
$$\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty} \left[\frac{4e^{-j \frac{\pi}{2}n}}{\pi(1-n^2)}(e^{-j\pi n}+1)\right]e^{-j \frac{\pi}{2}tn} $$

However, we have a division by zero at $n = 1$ and $n = -1 $. Is there any way to determine $D_{-1}$ and $D_1$?

Comment: You don't have a division by $0$ at $n=\pm 1$, you have the _indeterminate form_ $\dfrac 00$ because $e^{-jn\pi}+1 = 0$ when $n=\pm 1$. You _could_ use L'Hopital's rule (treating $n$ as a continuous variable instead of being integer-valued), but it is better to follow MattL's suggestion and evaluate separately for $n=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

You need to go back to the original definition of the Fourier coefficients via the integral, and treat $|n|=1$ as a special case. Your mistake happened there already (you divided by zero).

Comment: Can I just calculate the integral for $n = 1$ and $n = -1$ to determine these coefficients?

Comment: @JulyH.: Yes, sure, why not? The definition is valid for any value of $n$.